vb.net compiler using Mono in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm trying to create a vb.net question template for a module called 'coderunner' that runs in the Moodle VLE, allows teachers to set programming tasks for students which are then executed in a 'JOBE sever' sandbox and evaluated against assessment criteria but cannot get past the first hurdle.
I'm trying to install the mono vb.net compiler on a virtual private server running Ubuntu 24.04.
I've installed mono-complete, mcs works but the vbnc command does not appear to have been installed.
I've also tried cloning from the repository https://github.com/mono/mono-basic
But I'm getting an error "vbnc : Command line : error VBNC2017: The library 'System.Xml.dll' could not be found." which I cannot find a resolution for.
Tried installing various packages, also tried installing from source.

Mono is a chapter done and closed. Did you evaluate .NET 8 and why not switch to that? BTW, Mono VB was never mature enough so it's not in mono-complete.
